# Create hive external table from partitioned parquet files in Azure HDInsights

Tags: azure, hive, parquet, azure-hdinsight

I have data saved as parquet files in Azure blob storage. Data is partitioned by year, month, day and hour like:

`cont/data/year=2017/month=02/day=01/`

I want to create external table in Hive using following create statement, which I wrote using [this reference](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html).

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_name (uid string, title string, value string) 
PARTITIONED BY (year int, month int, day int) STORED AS PARQUET 
LOCATION 'wasb://cont@storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/data';
```

This creates table but has no rows when querying. I tried same create statement without `PARTITIONED BY` clause and that seems to work. So looks like issue is with partitioning.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After you create the partitioned table, run the following in order to add the directories as partitions

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

If you have a large number of partitions you might need to set **hive.msck.repair.batch.size**

> When there is a large number of untracked partitions, there is a
>   provision to run MSCK REPAIR TABLE batch wise to avoid OOME (Out of Memory Error). By giving
>   the configured batch size for the property hive.msck.repair.batch.size
>   it can run in the batches internally. The default value of the
>   property is zero, it means it will execute all the partitions at once.
>
> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

---

**Written by the OP:**

This will probably fix your issue, however if data is very large, it won't work. See relevant issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-12859).

As a workaround, there is another way to add partitions to Hive metastore one by one like:

`alter table table_name add partition(year=2016, month=10, day=11, hour=11)`

We wrote simple script to automate this alter statement and it seems to work for now.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I just found that statement in one docs. However, I am getting this error when running that: `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask`

So looks like there is some other issue.

Comment: @chhantyal It might be caused by the metastore schema verification, please refer to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool#HiveSchemaTool-MetastoreSchemaVerification to check whether the property `hive.metastore.schema.verification` is `true` in `hive-site.xml`. Or it might be caused by SQL Azure locked or deny some operations.

Comment: @chhantyal - not enough information. Check logs or run in DEBUG mode.

Comment: Try changing the logging to DEBUG

Comment: Have you try setting hive.msck.repair.batch.size?

Comment: Setting `hive.msck.repair.batch.size` is available only on new version (2.2.0) of Hive, which HDInsight doesn't support yet. Even then there seems to be some issue, which I linked in updated answer.